# Prove if $G$ is abelian, $g\in G$ is of maximal order, and $h \in G$ has finite order, then $|h|$ divides $|g|$.

Tags: abelian-groups

I've been playing around with the problem for a while now but haven't managed to make any progress. I would really appreciate a nudge in the right direction -- but please no full solutions.

**Attempt:**

Assume $|h|$ is finite but does not divide $|g|$. Then there is a prime integer $p$ such that $|g|=p^m r$ and $|h|=p^n s$, with $\gcd(r,s)=1$ and $m<n$. Note that
$$\left| g^{p^m} \right| = \frac{|g|}{\gcd\left( p^m, |g| \right)}=r$$
$$\left| h^{s} \right| =  \frac{|h|}{\gcd\left( s, |h| \right)}=p^n$$
thus $\gcd(\left| g^{p^m} \right|, \left| h^{s} \right|)=1$, so by a previous exercise we have
$$\left| g^{p^m}  h^{s} \right|=\left| g^{p^m} \right|\left| h^{s} \right| = p^n r .$$

Comment: You're very, very close. Take a long look at your last line. There is an immediate contradiction there.

Comment: @BenG. Since $m<n$ we have  $p^m<p^n$, in order for $g$ to be maximal order it would require $r>s$... So $$\left| g^{p^m} h^{s} \right|=p^n r>|h|=p^n s$$ and thus... hmm, I can't immediately see what I'm missing..

Comment: Compare $|g^{p^m}h^s|$ to $|g|$.

Comment: @BenG. Oh! $$\left| g^{p^m} h^{s} \right| =p^n r > p^m r = |g|$$ which contradicts $g$ being a maximal order element! I feel beyond silly for being blind to that for so long. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @BenG. If you're willing to rewrite your comment as an answer, I would be more than delighted to marked it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare $|g^{p^m}h^s|$ to $|g|$.